# Assembly BIOS call not working

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader, bios, x86-16

I am working with a simple assembly snippet to print a character to screen using the BIOS as a part of a bootloader. Here is the bootloader code.

```
[org 0x7c00]

[bits 16]

%include "a20_check.asm"


mov ah, 0x0e
mov al, 'H'
int 0x10

times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

This is the code for the *a20_check.asm* function, taken from [osdev.org](http://wiki.osdev.org/A20).

```
[bits 16]


; Returns: 0 in ax if the a20 line is disabled (memory wraps around)
;          1 in ax if the a20 line is enabled (memory does not wrap around)

check_a20:
pushf
push ds
push es
push di
push si

cli

xor ax, ax ; ax = 0
mov es, ax

not ax ; ax = 0xFFFF
mov ds, ax

mov di, 0x0500
mov si, 0x0510

mov al, byte [es:di]
push ax

mov al, byte [ds:si]
push ax

mov byte [es:di], 0x00
mov byte [ds:si], 0xFF

cmp byte [es:di], 0xFF

pop ax
mov byte [ds:si], al

pop ax
mov byte [es:di], al

mov ax, 0
je check_a20__exit

mov ax, 1

check_a20__exit:
pop si
pop di
pop es
pop ds
popf

ret
```

The problem appears to be in the last label, *check_a20__exit*. If I comment out `ret`, then the character prints to the screen. Otherwise, it does not print.

Can someone explain this problem to me?

Comment: Perhaps you should write a jump code after "mov ax, 1" which jumps to code beyond the last line of "check_a20__exit" My theory is that your code is not jumping to "check_a20__exit" from the line "je check_a20__exit" this is causing the code right after "je check_a20__exit" to getting executed, which also exeutes "check_a20__exit" since "check_a20__exit" is just a label, and not a function as in c++. Thus the ret statement us being called without a previous matching jump. Check the value of zero flag right before "je check_a20__exit" instruction.

Comment: Which is H/W environment in which this code is running? "mov ax,0" is trying to set zero flag by making accumulator register zero.

Comment: The code is running using qemu emulation using i386 architecture.

Comment: @SahilSingh : The [MOV](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html) instruction doesn't alter the flags.

Comment: @SahilSingh the flags for `je check_a20__exit` is set by `cmp byte [es:di], 0xFF`. The code for "A20" is not trivial and unless you actually know a lot about this stuff, don't try to guess how it works. And BTW that `ax` init to 0/1 can be rewritten in branch-less way: `sbb ax,ax` `inc ax`

Comment: I am sorry, it has been many years since I worked on assembly.

Answer (score 4):

If you think about your own description of your troubleshooting and then look at how you've included the code, it should be obvious what the problem is.

- First, you include your code for checking the A20 line
- That code ends with a `ret`
- Next we find the code that prints a character on the screen
- Finally we have null padding

Obviously, the `ret` is going to try to use whatever's currently at `SP` and switch the execution path there... but you've never called anything, so that data is just garbage.

Removing the `ret` allows it to "fall through" to your printing code.

Comment: Besides what you mention after printing the character they continue to execute code where none is specified (Potentially wandering memory). Should put some kind of infinite loop to avoid that.